# Defining inside an \edef

Tags: macros, expansion, nesting

```
The following throws an "Undefined control sequence" error:

\edef\testa{\edef\testb{foobar}\testb}
```

when it gets to expanding \testb.
This problem is also mentioned in "TEX by Topic" 12.6.2.
But no solution is given.

EDIT2, this is a minimal not-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{definition}[1]{\def\currentdef{#1}}{}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\contains[2]{%
    \edef\listarg{#1}%
    \xdef\needle{#2}%
    \expandafter\contains@sub\listarg,\relax\noexpand\@eolst%
}
\def\contains@sub#1,#2\@eolst{%
    \edef\match{#1}%
    \ifx\needle\match%
        true
    \else
        \ifx\relax#2\relax\else
            \contains@sub#2\@eolst%
        \fi
    \fi}

\newcommand\cond[1]{%
    \edef\test{\contains{\currentdef}{#1}}%
    \ifx\relax\test\relax\def\ommitthis\relax\fi%
    \@ifundefined{ommitthis}{#1}{}%
}

\makeatother

\def\test{test2}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{test2,test3}
    \cond{test3}
    \cond{\test}
    \cond{test1}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

`\cond` should check whether the given argument was listed in the surrounding definition. So test2 and test3 must be ommited and only test1 should be printed.

Comment: If you want the definition of `\testb` to be executed while expanding the definition of `\testa`, that's impossible. If you want the definition of `\testa` to contain the definition statement for `\testb`, then use `\noexpand\testb` (twice).

Comment: Actually I want the definition to be executed during the expansion. For some more context: I wrote a macro that tests whether one argument is contained in a ,-list given as the other argument. Now I'm using this macro in a `\edef` somewhere so that I can test the result with `\ifx`. But unfortunately the macro uses `\edef` itself...

Comment: `\edef` isn't expandable, so it's not expanded within an `\edef`!

Comment: Well I thought maybe it is possible to write the test part without edef, thus avoiding the problem. But of course I can post the contains thing too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to cycle through the list given as argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{definition}[1]
  {\def\currentdef{#1}}
  {}

\makeatletter
\def\cond#1{\edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \@tempswafalse
  \@for\@tempb:=\currentdef\do
    {\ifx\@tempa\@tempb\@tempswatrue\fi}%
  \if@tempswa\else\@tempa\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\test{test2}

\begin{definition}{test2,test3}
    \cond{test3}
    \cond{\test}
    \cond{test1}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

The `definition` environment stores the argument in the macro `\currentdef` (as you do). The macro `\cond` expands completely its argument and stores the result in `\@tempa`. Then sets the scratch conditional `\@tempswa` to false and, with the help of `\@for` compares `\@tempa` with each part of `\currentdef`; the block

```
\@for\@tempb=\LIST\do{<code>}
```

where `\LIST` expands to `a,b,c` (any comma separated list of tokens) executes `<code>` with `\@tempb` expanding to `a`, `b` and `c` in turn.

The `<code>`, in our case, is "check if `\@tempa` and `\@tempb` have the same meaning (expansion, here) and, if so, set `\if@tempswa` to true.

Finally `\cond` tests `\@iftempswa`: if it's true nothing else is done, otherwise `\@tempa` is expanded.

---

The same effect, but with even some improvements can be obtained with `expl3`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{definition}{m}
 { \canaaerus_store:n { #1 } } { }
\NewDocumentCommand{\cond}{m}
 { \canaaerus_check:x { #1 } }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \canaaerus_store:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_canaaerus_list_seq { , } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \canaaerus_check:n #1
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnF \l_canaaerus_list_seq { #1 } { #1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \canaaerus_check:n { x }

\seq_new:N \l_canaaerus_list_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The improvement is that spaces around the list are stripped off, so

```
\begin{definition}{test2 , test3 }
```

is just as good as the input without spaces.

The strategy is the same, but the argument to `definition` is stored in a sequence (as a bonus, spaces around the list argument are stripped off). The cycle works similarly as before: we check whether the argument to `\canaaerus_check:x` (completely expanded) appears in the sequence; if not, the argument is output.

Notice how we get the complete expansion: the macro defined is `\canaaerus_check:n`, but we create also a variant so that using

```
\canaaerus_check:x {<tokens>}
```

is thus pretty much equivalent to saying

```
\edef\@tempa{<tokens>}\expandafter\canaaerus_check:n\expandafter{\@tempa}
```

(I apologize for the horrible mixture of LaTeX3 and primitive syntax, but it's just by way of example). The convenience of the "variant" method should be self-evident.